# What's the canonical link for comments being "second-class citizens"?

Tags: support, comments

Comments are often described as "second-class citizens" on Stack Exchange:

- > Comments are purposely second-class citizens, but this seems like privileging them--protection for comments that should be removed!
  >  [Allow flagging a comment after upvoting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104184/allow-flagging-a-comment-after-upvoting-it)
- [Make comments look like second class citizens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279859/make-comments-look-like-second-class-citizens)
- > While I agree comments are second class citizens, ...
  >  [Discrimination against comments!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197047/discrimination-against-comments)

Etc.

When I refer to comments being "second-class citizens", I'd like to add a reliable reference to show that I'm not just a random person on the Internet stating an anti-comment opinion.

Thus, I want to include a link to a reliable reference.  But I don't know which link to use...

**Question**: What's the canonical link for comments being "second-class citizens"?

It's not on the help page: [Privileges > comment everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks.  It's good, but is it canonical?  E.g. it's not written by Stack Exchange staff.  (It's predated by [Allow flagging a comment after upvoting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104184/allow-flagging-a-comment-after-upvoting-it).)

Comment: Shog9 [set it as a FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/214173/timeline#history_23e9d966-fcc7-4694-a3c8-4ab90ecc47c1)

Comment: They're not any more. People are routinely and habitually using comments as a place to answer questions, and the system/company/community all seem fine with this in the main. :(